# Converting a string into a List and then using Entity Framework to insert into Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections

I am converting a string into a list and then trying to use entity framework to insert it into a DB. The issue that I am having is that I don't know how to save the changes to the DB.

This is the code that I am trying to use and is where the string is converted to a list:

```
if (intCounter == 0)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<foo>>(jsonString).Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

Then in a seperate class below.

```
ConvertJson.Convert<CouncilEvent>(strResponseJSONContent, intCounter);
```

The Entity Framework Model that I am trying to use for the list.

```
namespace foo.Models
{
    public partial class foo
    {
        public foo()
        {
            this.EventDates = new List<EventDate>();
        }

        public System.Guid foo_PK { get; set; }
        public string EntityID { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string Address3 { get; set; }
        public bool Adult { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The class foo contains properties that match those in the string.

It is this foo that I am then trying to insert into the DB. foo is also part of my Entity Framework model.

I have never used a list in this situation before and I thought it would just be a matter of using `db.SaveChanges()` but that doesn't seem to work. Where would I place the necessary lines of code such as using `(db = new contextFoo)` and `db.SaveChanges()`. Also do I need to add the items? I haven't because I thought I was already adding them to the class and therefore didn't need to do this manually?

Answer (score 0):

`db.SaveChanges()` will only 'update' your database to what was changed. So, you need to add something to the database, and then call `SaveChanges()` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the list to add the objects to the context, then call `SaveChanges()`...

```
var councilEvents = ConvertJson.Convert<CouncilEvent>(strResponseJSONContent, intCounter);

using (var db = new contextFoo()) 
{
    foreach (var councilEvent in councilEvents)
    {
        db.CouncilEvents.Add(councilEvent);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks mate. This does not seem to work for the situation when the json string contains multiple ie. category1"a,b,c,d,e" category2"a,b,c,d,e" as I have the primary key generated by the db. Is there a maintainable way to get past this constraint?